# Where can I find the Maven installation directory in Eclipse 3.4

Tags: java, maven-2, eclipse-plugin

I have installed m2eclipse plugin from [http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/](http://web.archive.org/web/20150524020820/http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/). Now I want to use that as a standalone build tool but I am unable to find the installation directory. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 20):

Execute the following command:

```
mvn --version
```

Example Result:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19  14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: `D:\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin`\..
Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

The Maven Home will show you where maven is installed.

Comment: In my case this returns `Maven home: C:\path\my\project\EMBEDDED` which is an inexistent directory.

Comment: Im searchi,ng my home directory because mvn -- version is not working. I want to add directory to environmental variables . How can I find it ?

Answer (score 7):

I have both the plugin (with its embedded maven instance) and a full maven download. Both should end up using the same repository in something like `C:\Documents and Settings\user\.m2`.

There are a few cases where you need a full maven download anyways. For example, trying to build a groovy maven plugin crashes with the embedded maven, but works fine for the full download.

You can also specify from the preference pane in Eclipse, to use a differen maven installation than the embedded one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

My Eclipse is using a Default Maven Version (3.0.4). So try this:

**Option 1**: Restart
Restart your Eclipse and look if the Maven configuration is right again
under "Windows" -> "Preferences" -> "Maven" -> "Installations"

**Option 2**: Select/Configure your Embedded "Maven Runtime"
Right-click on your project -> "Run As..." -> under "Maven Build", Tab "Main" -> take the "External" Maven in the Drop-Down Box. Then run it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you want.
m2eclipse is a **plugin** for Eclipse, thus it must be run inside Eclipse.

To have a standalone build tool, I suggest that you just download directly the [Maven2 binaries files](http://maven.apache.org/download.html), and install it on your computer, if it is not already done!

For your information, all plugins are stored in the eclipse-dir/plugins directory, as a subdirectory or as a JAR file.