# Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am totally a newbie with Maven.
I want to create a Maven project with Eclipse Juno EE with archetype "webapp". I installed "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (incubation)" and I also have installed "Maven Integration for Eclipse" (found it on Installed tab of Eclipse Marketplace).
When I try to create new Project from **File->New_>Maven Project**, I obtain error:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\PEP35KD\.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\PEP35KD\.m2\repository)
```

It happens for all kinds of archetype.
I am using a proxy, and I create file settings.xml under C:\Documents and Settings\PEP35KD.m2\ with this content:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>myId</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>rete\pep35kd</username>
        <password>XXXX</password>
        <host>XXXX</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Please, consider that it seems that I cannot use mvn command from command line (command not found). I never installed Maven itself, I thinked that plugin is just enough: is it a correct assumption?

**UPDATE** Problem is definitely related to proxy. By:

- Installing Maven on local PC;
- Installing Maven Eclipse from Eclipse
  Market Place;
- Setting Maven Install directory to local PC Maven dir, instead of default Embedded Maven,

everything works as expected. I cannot really understand why, but probably firewall is blocking traffic with Maven servers.

Comment: Is your proxy username really "rete\pep35kd"?

Comment: Yes, it is just the username I use setting Proxy in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me. Finally I solved the problem: See detailed steps at my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse/25807975#25807975

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I fixed this problem by following the solution to [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15789286/7989)

> I had the same problem. I fixed it by adding the maven archetype catalog to eclipse. Steps are provided below: (Please note the https protocol)
>
> 1. Open Window > Preferences
> 2. Open Maven > Archetypes
> 3. Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:
>
>    - Catalog File: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
>    - Description: maven catalog

Comment: To me it says that doesn't exists the archetype catalog.

Comment: I get an empty catalog file with no templates or whatsoever...

Comment: there is no catalog file available anymore at this link.

Comment: It seems to be back now.

Comment: I want to create webservice project with maven and get this error `Can't resolve Archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archtypes:jersey-quickstart-web:2.16` :(

Comment: @TomDestry I am still not able to resolve the issue getting the same error.

Comment: it says "Remote catalog is empty" when checked with 'Verify...' button

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: Though this works, but sometimes some other issue could make this solution ineffective. I had the issue with mirrors in my maven settings.xml. Once I commented out those in settings.xml, it worked for me.

Comment: In the meantime, the catalog URL has changed to HTTPS.
So, use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml. This should be working fine.

Comment: @Gobliins, Yes. It will be empty. But we need to wait for some time to update.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that you have your proxy settings correct, you may have missed out pointing Eclipse to the intended `settings.xml` file. This happens often when you have both Maven installed as a snap in, and an external installation outside Eclipse. You need to tell Eclipse which Maven installation it should use, and which settings.xml file it should be looking for.

First check that the settings.xml file contains your proxy settings.

[image]

Next, check that the user settings.xml file here contains your proxy settings.

[image]

If you have made any changes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: Checked it again, and I am using correct settings.xml everywhere (the default one with proxy added).

Comment: one more thing to go, noticed that you have put your domain\username. Could you remove the domain, and use just the username?

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed.

Comment: @OhChinBoon is it necessary to have an environment variable when build in eclipse?, i have not resolved problem

Answer (score 10):

Adding the following inside "mirrors" section in the user setting.xml file worked for me.

```
<mirror>
  <id>ibiblio.org</id>
  <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. There are also some others mirrors that can be used (`<id>uk.maven.org</id><url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>`, `<id>central</id><url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>`, etc.). This URL can be useful: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml .

Answer (score 7):

i found the easiest way was to just remove/delete the .m2 folder and recreate it, putting back your settings.xml configuration details(if applicable).

Answer (score 6):

Add your `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable, edit your Path to include `%MAVEN_HOME%/bin` then try creating the project manually with Maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.program -DartifactId=Program -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Then import the existing Maven project to Eclipse.

Comment: I cannot use "mvn" command line. Is it necessary to install Maven before the Eclipse plugin? It can seem a obvious question, but I expected some error from Eclipse if Maven was required and not available.

Comment: To use the mvn command, you have to add the enviroment variable. Se here for more information: https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37290050

Comment: Also, of course, if you haven't yet, you have to configure maven so it works correctly on Eclipse. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven, and it's all there (Installation dir, settings, etc.)

Comment: I cannot find Maven directory installation on PC.
From this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289800/where-can-i-find-the-maven-installation-directory-in-eclipse-3-4, I understand that I need full Maven installation to use it on command line, isn't it?

Comment: Under Windows-Preferences->Maven->Installations, installation selected to launh Maven is set to Embedded (no path)

Comment: Download maven here: http://maven.apache.org/ - Extract it to C:\, then you're good to go. Embedded Maven is annoying to mess with the configuration, always set your own.

Comment: I installed Maven, set Maven installation to new installed software, but creating project from Eclipse still gives same error. Also using suggested command line I obtain Build Failure (lots of failing to retireve plugin description and "No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups"

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? In that case, edit settings.xml (C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml) to add that information there.

Comment: Yes, I added proxy section (see my first post... I just covered password and host section with XXX)

Comment: I used settings.xml (with my proxy added) from conf directory of Maven install dir also in .m2 user directory...

Answer (score 4):

You can resolve it by configuring settings.xml in Eclipse.

Go to Window --> Preferences --> Maven --> User Settings --> select the actual path of settings.xml

Answer (score 3):

I find it solution
  http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/7c42f9d698a4/java-create-maven-project-could-not-resolve-archetype-connection-refused.html

We can see the origin of the problem : Connection refused: connect

I have already do this :

1) Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections. I put in Manual with the url and port of my proxy for HTTP protocol. It works because before this, Spring Tool Suite did not want to update. After, it's okay.

2) Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings. In Global Settings, is empty. In User Settings, I put the path to settings.xml. In this file, i have :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Goto 
Preferences: 
-> Maven 
Click 'Add Remote Catalog'
File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Desc: Catalog

Answer (score 2):

click windows-> preferences->Maven. uncheck "Offline" check box. This was not able to download archetype which I was using.
When I uncheck it, Everything worked smooth.

Comment: Worked for me. Had issues with this check box before. It is so annoying,

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that your settings.xml file defined in maven/conf folder defines a location that it cannot access

Answer (score 1):

This might sound silly, but make sure the "Offline" checkbox in Maven settings is unchecked. I was trying to create a project and got this error until I noticed the checkbox.

Comment: Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you have to install [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) on your workstation. You need also to install M2E, what you obviously did. Not all distributions of Juno have it pre-installed.

Then configure your Eclipse so it can find your Maven install. In the menu Window -> Preferences, then open the Maven section. In your right panel, you have a list of the Maven installations Eclipse knows. Add your installation and select it instead of the embedded Maven provided with M2E. Don't forget to set the "Global settings from installation directory" field with the path to the settings.xml of your Maven installation.

Which leads us to the settings.xml. If the above doesn't solve your problem, you will have to configure your Maven. More infos [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: I installed Maven, set Maven installation to new installed software, but creating project from Eclipse still gives same error.
I tried to lanunbch this command from command line:
    mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.program -DartifactId=Program -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false

but I have a lot of errors like this:
    Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

And final build failure:
    No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error while creating web-app in eclipse and resolved the problem just by cleaning (deleting all files from) and rebuilding the maven repository

Answer (score -3):

You will need to install the m2eclipse or any other maven plugin in your eclipse. Some eclipse come with maven and its plugins installed. Otherwise go to Help->software Install, select All sites, filter list with maven, and then install the plugin. Then look at [this](http://rajanpupa.blogspot.com/2013/08/overview-i-still-remember-my-initial.html) link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Without this plugin, OP wouldn't have been able to see the "File->New->Maven Project" in the first place