# Error while creating Maven project In Eclipse using archetype selection

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I am trying to create maven project it is showing below error

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
```

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: can u provide your pom file

Comment: @  Kamlesh Arya
Failed to create the project.

Comment: Try answers in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Maven project, could not resolve archetype, connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297947/create-maven-project-could-not-resolve-archetype-connection-refused)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you configured your maven in eclipse properly
1.  Go to preference-->Maven-->Installation
           In this add the path of working maven directory
2.  Go to preference-->Maven-->User Setting
           In this add the path of your maven_directory/conf/setting.xml
Try with these setting let us know if it works...cheers

Comment: @ Gaurav Katkamwar
My working maven directory is External C:\ProgramFiles\Maven(3.1.1)
User settings is C:\Program Files\maven\conf\settings.xml

Comment: try updating user settings as C:\ProgramFiles\Maven(3.1.1)\conf\settings.xml

Comment: Please verify if you are using any proxy settings, these setting should be properly configured in settings.xml

Comment: @ Gaurav Katkamwar
Yes i am using the proxy settings. how to configure in settings.xml?

Comment: add following under <settings></settings> of settings.xml 
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>your_id</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>your_username</username>
      <password>your_password</password>
      <host>your_host</host>
      <port>port</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|192.168.*</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    
  </proxies>

Comment: @  Gaurav Katkamwar
what to write in ur id? and in your host?

Comment: id could be anything and host is your proxy ipaddress it can be host name also

Comment: @ Gaurav katkamwar
I edited the settings.xml like this but still getting the error
-<proxies> -<proxy> <id>Shanx</id> <active>true</active> <protocol>http</protocol> <username>20063521</username> <password>******</password> <host>10.9.100.73</host> <port>3128</port> <nonProxyHosts>local.net|192.168.*</nonProxyHosts> </proxy> </proxies>

Comment: @ Gaurav katkamwar
Getting this while setting the user settings in Window->preferences->maven->user settings 
Unable to parse user settings file; Non-parseable settings C:\Program Files\maven\conf\sett...G seen ...on in this list marked as active will be used.\n   |-->\n  <proxies>... @104:12

Comment: check out this link http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse luna EE version, 
GO TO 
Windows -> Preferences -> Maven and uncheck the following option

`Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories.`

This option is checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add maven archetype catalog to eclipse

1. Window>Preferences
2. Maven>Archetypes
3. Add Remote Catalog and add the following:

   Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

   Description : maven catalog

After adding archetype,restart eclipse.

Comment: restart eclipse->new Maven project->catalog:All Catalogs->Filter:Web

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse over Windows 7, then make sure you are running eclipse with enough privileges (Run as administrator). Furthermore, configure the Proxy settings for MAVEN as folks stated in the previous answers, and make sure that Eclipse Proxy settings are set too.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the checkbox coming on first popup while creating Maven module.
Checkbox name - **"Create a sample project(skip archetype selection)"** and go ahead with rest of the procedure, you will not get any errors.