# gc overhead limit exceeded while retrieving archetypes

Tags: eclipse, maven, out-of-memory

[image: when I am creating a maven project and while archetypes is being retrieved ,I am getting this error called gc overhead limit exceeded]

I tried to increase the memory allocation for Eclipse by increasing the Xms and Xmx values -Xms512m and -Xmx1024m respectively in eclipse.ini but still not resolved.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse Oxygen? Why not increase `-Xmx` more?

Comment: What is your java version? What is the size of your RAM? Try to increase Xmx even more

Comment: @howlger i am using eclipse luna. Tried increasing it to 4096. Not solved.

Comment: Tried increasing it to 4096. Not solved. My RAM is 8GB. @bdshadow

Comment: @bdshadow java version is 1.8

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with the latest version of Eclipse, of the Maven plug-in and of Maven?

Comment: Try to go to the workspace directory. Find there .metadata directory. There must be a .log file inside. Try to find OutOfMemoryError error there. What has been logged before it? You can add it to your question, or use https://pastebin.com/ to share it with us

Comment: @howlger tried updating luna version that i am using but error remains same. So installed oxygen-eclipse, and working. Thank-you for your help.

Comment: @bdshadow tried it but error remains same. Now oxygen-eclipse, and working there. Thank-you for your help.

Comment: @aakashrajani Great, I added it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

what finally works for me is opening eclipse in a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, go to **Maven -> Archetypes** and make sure that **Nexus Indexer** is disabled. I'm guessing that, because there are so many archetypes on the maven nexus, you just go out of memory trying to fetch it. Make sure that **Default Local** is still enabled and every archetype that you have used before will still be visible.

@user2735883, The reason why a new workspace would work as well is because by default the option to download the repository index on startup is disabled. If you enable it, it will start pulling the nexus archetypes and you'll go out of memory again

Answer (score -1):

[Most of the known *out of memory* errors in the Eclipse Maven plug-in are alread fixed.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?list_id=16648680&longdesc=OutOfMemoryError&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&product=m2e&query_format=advanced) Therefore, an update of your more than three years old Maven plug-in could help. Either [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) and install the latest Eclipse IDE from scratch or **update your existing Eclipse IDE** from Luna **to Oxygen**:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites*** click ***Add...***:

   - *Name:* **`Oxygen`**
   - *Location:* **`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen`**
2. ***Help > Check for Updates***

Comment: Nothing to do with the link mention or the procedure you suggest. There STILL a problem with the Nexus indexer and this workaround work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype

Comment: @SteveS. For the questioner, an update to Eclipse Oxygen solved the problem (see comments). Obviously, there is another problem when using a proxy which leads also to an _out of memory_ error but for other reasons.