# unable to create maven project in eclipse photon

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I have been trying to create a maven project in eclipse photon.I also tried checking proxy settings,linked a "settings.xml" file in user settings,linked a "catalog.xml" under archetype.But it didn't worked.Eclipse is configured with java 8 version.I am unable to upload photos so i will describe.
These are the steps I followed while creating Maven project.
File->New->other->Maven->Maven Project->Next->Next->Selected Archetype-quickstart1.1->Next->provided Artifact and Group Id and Finish.
Here I'm getting could not resolve archetype error.

Comment: Specify "it didn't worked". Some error message / you can't find the maven project option / ... ?

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you.can you please make it some more clearer.

Comment: I am asking you to elaborate your post and specify your question. "It didn't work" is not very helpful for identifying the problem and no one will be able to answer your question this way.

Comment: What steps did you take? _File > New > Other...: Maven > Maven Project_ and then?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear the issue you are facing and how you are creating the maven project. Eclipse comes with a great in built maven support. It's not necessary to configure **settings.xml** unless you are using your own repository instead of the default repository **.m2**

However assuming that you have installed Eclipse Photon correctly. Here are the steps involved in creation of simple maven project.

Click on File-->New-->Others.
On the new window look for maven and click on **Maven Project**.
This will launch new window **New Maven Project*. If you don't want to select available archetypes, then click on the checkbox named "Create Simple Project(Skip Archetype Selection)" and click on next.
Fill in your project details and click on finish. That's it.
Eclipse will generate a fresh maven project for you.

The other configurations are required based on the type of project you are creating.
Hope this helps !!!

Comment: I did it in the same way.I have chosen maven-archetype-quickstart version 1.1.

Comment: Can you please post the error or issue you are facing ?

Comment: could not resolve archetype  from any of org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 configured properties

Comment: It seems you're missing catalog.xml file. Get it from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml and add it into eclipse. Follow steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype

Comment: I have added it.But it is still throwing the same problem

Comment: Can you edit your question with the steps you are following. Also include the exact step on which the error occurred. Include screenshots, if necessary.