# could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven.architype.quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I have tried deleting .m2 folder in the users and tried to open a new project again  but that process did not work.it has given me the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype)

Comment: this did not help i have done everything in the above link, still i am not able to create maven project