# Issue with creating maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven.architype.quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories,
I have tried deleting .m2 repository,adding setting.xml file in .m2 folder -I have tried this things but they did not work for me - can anyone help out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype)

Comment: Try `Windows-> Preference-> Maven -> User settings`. Browse and select `settings.xml` and then reboot your IDE.

Comment: Can you check your internet connectivity and paste screenshot or log?

Comment: for setting.xml , where to find Id,username,password,host,port