# No suitable archetypes found. Please make sure that the proper maven repositories are configured and indexes are up to date

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, aem, archetypes

I am setting a development environment for Adobe Experience Manager. I installed AEM Dev Tools in Eclipse but i get the error " No suitable archetypes found. Please make sure that the proper maven repositories are configured and indexes are up to date." when I try to create a AEM Sample Multi-Module Project.

Answer (score 1):

This is shown in either of the two cases :

1. If you are behind a proxy.
2. Eclipse can't read the archetype because its not there in its catalog.

For the first issue check if you are able to build the same code in your personal system (any system not behind proxy).

For the second issue, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype) and try :

I had the same problem. I fixed it by adding the maven archetype catalog to eclipse. Steps are provided below:

```
1. Open Window > Preferences
2. Open Maven > Archetypes
3. Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:
Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Description: maven catalog
```

Comment: I tried your second solution, but am still getting the same error as the original poster. When I click the "Archetype" dropdown, nothing appears. Now I'll try your first suggestion, but first... How do you check to see if you are behind a proxy?