# Error in Creating a Maven project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I just started to learn Hibernate in Java and i was supposed to use Maven Project but while creating project i am facing this error why i am getting this error almost tried all of the online saying still no improvement it fails ...Thanks in Advance

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Manoj Selvin.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Manoj Selvin.m2\repository)

Comment: It is quite difficult to judge since you've not provided your ```pom.xml``` file, but your problem points to the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype

Comment: Looks to me like you're specifying a version named "RELEASE".  I doubt that is a valid version name.